# How to load data into jqgrid based on url

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, url, jqgrid

I want to load data into jqgrid based on url's. In `edit mode` I get the data from below method based on userId.

```
url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllUserOffersList/${userBean.userId }'
```

and in `Addmode` I get the data from below url

```
url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllOffersList/'
```

I check the if condition based on userId but it is not possible to place it, shown me an error.

```
if (userBean.userId != null) {
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllOffersList/';
} else {
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllUserOffersList/${userBean.userId }';
}
```

when I check above condition in below code it shows

> Syntax error on token ":", ; expected

I want to use only one url

**Here is my Code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//jqGrid
$("#userOffersList").jqGrid({

    url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllOffersList/',
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllUserOffersList/${userBean.userId }',
    datatype: "json",   
    colNames:['Select','Category','Offer Text','Provider Name'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'isSelect',index:'isSelect',formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false},editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions:{value:'true:false', defaultValue: 'false'},sortable:false,width:50},
        {name:'category',index:'category',width:100},               
        {name:'offerText',index:'offerText',width:350},
        {name:'providerName',index:'providerName',width:250},
        ],
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],
        rownumbers: true,  
        pager: '#pagerDiv',
        sortname: 'offerText',  
        viewrecords: true,  
        sortorder: "asc",
        autowidth:'true',
    });
    $('#gridContainer div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
    $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', window.innerHeight * .55);
    $('#load_userOffersList').width("130");
    $("#userOffersList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDiv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"20%"});
});
```

**JSP Page:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="gridContainer" >
        <table id="userOffersList"></table>
        <div id="pagerDiv"></div>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please copy paste the code below and try if this work. This should clear all your syntax errors:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            //jqGrid
            $("#userOffersList").jqGrid({
                <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty userBean.userId}">
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin/getAllOffersList/',
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin/getAllUserOffersList/${userBean.userId}',
                </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['Select', 'Category', 'Offer Text', 'Provider Name'],
                colModel: [
                    {name: 'isSelect', index: 'isSelect', formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled: false}, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: 'true:false', defaultValue: 'false'}, sortable: false, width: 50},
                    {name: 'category', index: 'category', width: 100},
                    {name: 'offerText', index: 'offerText', width: 350},
                    {name: 'providerName', index: 'providerName', width: 250}
                ],
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                rownumbers: true,
                pager: '#pagerDiv',
                sortname: 'offerText',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                autowidth: 'true'
            });


            $('#gridContainer div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
            $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', window.innerHeight * .55);
            $('#load_userOffersList').width("130");
            $("#userOffersList").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerDiv', {edit: false, add: false, del: false});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline: true, width: "20%"});
        });
```

Please always try to use **JSTL** instead of **scriptlets**.

Comment: @udaykiran pulipati - I've update the answer based on your complete code. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: @udaykiranpulipati - I have updated my answer. Cleared syntax errors, added JSTL instead of scriptlets. Please copy paste that code and try please and let me know. Fingers crossed!

Comment: your code contains mistake. It is wrong to add JSTL tags in jQuery

Comment: Why is it wrong? Is it NOT working? IF you can add scriptlets its far better to add jstl! Your original code contains sriptlets which is bad and never recommended? Can you please educate me on how jstl shouldn't be added unless it's a separate Java script file (in your case I don't think it is)?